# Image crop picker save images to gallery on click from camera in react native

Tags: react-native, imagepicker, react-native-image-picker

Hi I am using react native image crop picker and using this code

```
ImagePicker.openCamera({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      compressImageQuality: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 0.7 : 0.8,
      cropping: false,
      // includeBase64: true,
    })
```

But the problem is that when i am using this it saves images in the temp folder. So I want to know how can i save images to phone gallery on Click from camera.r